# How does the CPU distinguish 'CALL rel16' (E8 cw) and 'CALL rel32' (E8 cd)?

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set, instruction-encoding

How does the CPU distinguish `CALL rel16` (E8 cw) and `CALL rel32` (E8 cd)?

According to [this site](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html), mirroring the Intel architecture manuals, the opcodes for `CALL rel16` and `CALL rel32` are `E8 cw` and `E8 cd`, respectively.

This has made me wonder, how does the CPU distinguish these opcodes from each other, since `E8 cw` might be a prefix of `E8 cw`?

Comment: I assume "this site" is supposed to have been a hyperlink?

Comment: one "this site" could be here: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html

Comment: Sorry, @Tommylee2k - I've inserted the link.

Answer (score 13):

The prefix `66` is used to toggle between 16 and 32 bit operand size. So, in 16 bit operation modes, `E8 cw` is `CALL rel16` and `66 E8 cd` is `CALL rel32`, while in 32 bit operation mode, `E8 cd` is `CALL rel32` and `66 E8 cw` is `CALL rel16`.

In long mode (64 bit mode), `CALL rel16` seems to be unavailable according to the Intel manuals. `CALL rel32` works like in 32 bit mode but the `rel32` immediate is sign extended to 64 bit and added to `rip` instead of `eip`.

Comment: Thanks! However, I think it is weird why the Intel manual doesn't mention this prefix (see the site I've linked to).

Comment: The manual does say that, @Shuzheng. Under "Near Call", it says: *"The operand-size attribute determines the size of the target operand (16 or 32 bits)."*

Comment: @Shuzheng The prefix `66` applies to all instructions that are available in 16 bit and in 32 bit and it works the same way in all of them. Thus, there is no need to explain this over and over again in each instruction's documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray - I thought they meant whether a 16 or 32 bit operant is given as argument.

Comment: @Shuzheng The operand size attribute is determined by the current operation mode and the presence of an operand size override prefix (66).