# Intel XED: different function call addresses when decoding the same instruction

Tags: decode, elf, disassembly, function-call, xed

Consider the C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void greet(void){
    printf("Hello!\n");
}

int main (){
    greet();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc to a 64-bit ELF called *hello*.

Then in my first experiment, I disassembled (decoded) **the whole** .text section using XED as follows:

```
./xed -i hello
```

I am interested in the function call to *greet*, which was disassembled as follows:

```
XDIS 1168: CALL    BASE    E8DCFFFFFF     call 0x1149 <greet>
```

So far it looks fine since 0x1149 is truly the entry to the *greet* function.

But supposing that the string "E8DCFFFFFF" is the equivalent hex instruction, the confusion arises: in a second experiment with XED, I decided to disassemble **only the function call instruction**, i.e. the hex string "E8DCFFFFFF", as follows:

```
./xed -d E8DCFFFFFF
```

and here is the result:

```
ICLASS:     CALL_NEAR
CATEGORY:   CALL
EXTENSION:  BASE
IFORM:      CALL_NEAR_RELBRz
ISA_SET:    I86
ATTRIBUTES: FIXED_BASE0 MPX_PREFIX_ABLE SCALABLE STACKPUSH0 
SHORT:      call 0xffffffe1
```

I was expecting **call 0x1149** but I got **call 0xffffffe1**. Can anybody explain it please?

Comment: **The operand is relative** -- notice iform CALL_NEAR_RELBRz says REL. (1168+5)+(-24) is 1149 but (0+5)+(-24) is -1f. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376787/need-help-understanding-e8-asm-call-instruction-x86 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926175/why-does-e8-f2-ff-ff-ff-translate-to-call-0xfffffff7 also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882315/how-does-the-cpu-distinguish-call-rel16-e8-cw-and-call-rel32-e8-cd .

Comment: Thanks a lot! So we can note that in the actual instruction **E8DCFFFFFF**, the 32-bit signed offset **FFFFFFDC** = -0x24 is relative to the address of the next instruction after CALL (here 0x1168 + 5), but in the decoded XED result, the 32-bit signed offset **FFFFFFE1** = -0x1F is relative to the address of the CALL instruction itself. Do you have any idea why XED does this? I mean why it doesn't decode **E8DCFFFFFF** to **CALL 0xFFFFFFDC**?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I forgot to mention you in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't speak for Intel, but my guess would be they think that people who disassemble a program would like to see instantly where a call (or jump etc) goes rather than have to do manual arithmetic every time. Decades ago I debugged code on PDP-11 (more exactly LSI-11/2 and /23) using console ODT and I probably spent weeks of my life adding offsets that the computer could have done in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot for you informative comments!